# Does watch work with Jade?

Tags: node.js, pug

I want to watch my jade files and compile them, but it appears it does not work

```
jade client/jade --watch --out public
```

When I change `client/jade/draft.jade` it does not re-compile. I saw a post, saying it does not work with directories? Is it not fixed yet? Is there a workaround or something? Must I watch all files manually?

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jadejs/p_slRuISjVg/lL_uxgD6uB0J

Comment: Wait a second? Why do your Jade-Files have a Stylus extension?

Comment: @Amberlamps, ops thats a typo, the actual file is `draft.jade`

Answer (score 16):

What you have now says "watch the directory for changes". If you add or remove a file from the directory, it will recompile all the files. However, because it is only watching the directory (which is really just a file itself) and not the files in the directory, changing one of the files will not trigger a compile.

To watch all jade files in `client/jade`

```
$ jade --watch client/jade/*.jade --out public
```

This doesn't truly watch the directory, it just expands the jade command to watch all jade files present when you start, rather than having to type them all out. If you add a file after beginning the watch, then you'll need to restart it.